# HTML script doesn't wait until previous script is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loading, src

I get the `testFile.js` filename from url parameters, so it is loaded dynamically.
Then i do:

```
    <script>jQuery.getScript('testFolder/testFile.js');</script>
    <script src="ok1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script src="ok2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
```

`testFile.js` has:
`function getFile0(){}`

`ok1.js` has:

```
function getFile1(){} 
function getFile2(){} 
function getFile3(){}
```

`ok2.js` has:
`var _getFiles = [getFile0(), getFile1(), getFile2(), getFile2()];`

Although, it is supposed to load first the `testFile.js`, then `ok1.js` and **finally** `ok2.js`, i get this error for ok2.js: `Uncaught ReferenceError: getFile0 is not defined`

I have tried plenty of stuff like:

```
jQuery.getScript('testFolder/testFile.js').done(function() {
    jQuery.getScript('ok1.js').done(function() {
        jQuery.getScript('ok2.js');
    });
});
```

it is loading without error, but the page is not working as it should.

Comment: **All: This is just a typo-level problem.** uzer123, please refer to [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). `getScript` is **asynchronous**. Nothing in that code waits for `testFile.js` to be loaded.

Comment: Did you try: `<script src='testFolder/testFile.js'></script>`

Comment: Your `.done(..)` version should work, so "page is not working as it should" is probably the XY Problem.

Comment: @freedomn-m Agreed, it's never lupus, but iy's always a XY problem. If the scripts are loading as intended, why indeed is the page "not working as it should"?

Comment: i know getScript is asynchronous but the <script></script> is blocked. So, i thought the <script>getScript</script> will run before everything else because the <script> is waiting..no?
@freedomn-m i had tried it, and it is working.. 
Using the .done(..), a function that is loaded in ok1.js cannot be seen in ok2.js..which is strange..isn't it?

Comment: "The `<script>` is waiting* - yes, everything inside the script tag runs before moving to the next script tag.  By that, what runs is the call to `getScript`, which returns immediately so everything "inside the script tag" has run, but the async part of getScript has not run, because it's async.

Comment: @freedomn-m i see..thanks for the clarification.. Finally i solve it by doing this edit at ok2.js file: `jQuery.get('testFolder/testFile.js', function() { //all the ok2.js contents });`